# Prevent Visual Studio from relinking when dependency change

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution where I have several DLL projects.
MainDLL depends on SmallDLL.
If I make a local change in SmallDLL - without changing the exported API - just small change in a local function - MainDLL gets relinked.

Question 1: what is the rational behind relinking MainDLL - SmallDLL is not built into MainDLL - it is picked up at runtime? If I build only SmallDLL, MainDLL works perfectly fine. If I change SmallDLL's API, some of the headers will change, so some of MainDLL's files would have to be recompiled - then the relink is perfectly justified, but why relink for the local change?

Question 2: Is there any way to prevent such relinking? I need the dependency between MainDLL's project and SmallDLL's, so that when I run MainDLL's project after making a change to SmallDLL, I want SmallDLL to get rebuilt.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Question 1: when SmallDll gets re-linked, a new import library gets generated with the new timestamp (even if it's byte-for-byte identical to the old one). Build process sees the updated timestamp and assumes the import library has changed (it has no way to learn otherwise), at which point it has no choice but to re-link MainDLL.

Answer (score 0):

In VisualStudio 2008, check the "Build and run" options through
"Options" / "Projects and solutions" / "Build and run" / "On Run, when projects are out of date", and select "Prompt to build" or "Never build".
If you choose to not rebuild automatically, remember you will have to do it manually when your interfaces change.